# Publishing local printers in Remote Desktop sessions

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, printer, remote-access

My client has users of an ERP application spread across 50 locations. In each location, there will be multiple users. The ERP is hosted in a central server which has Windows 2012 Server 64-bit.

The idea is to buy Windows Remote Desktop CALs to access the ERP. One of the requirements is that each user should be able to print to his local printer directly from the ERP application, and also export reports to his local hard disk.

I have heard that sometimes there are issues in using the local printer in the Remote Desktop session, especially when the client OS is Windows XP, as the printer drivers may not be compatible with the Remote OS.

Note that each user may have separate version and edition of Windows, starting from Windows XP. Some users may have XP, others may have Win 7 or WIn 10. Some may be on 32-bit, others may be on 64-bit. Each user may have a different model of printer which may be connected directly to his machine, or may be on his local LAN.

Will this setup work seamlessly? Since Citrix is too expensive, the customer's inclination is to go for RDP CALs.

Comment: Did you look into the 'Microsoft Easy Print' feature? Yes, there can be issues, but, the resolutions as well. Basically, the .Net version, remote desktop client version have to be the same or at least the expexcted compatible versions.

Comment: Where can I get a document on the compatible versions? The problem is by the time we identify issues and try to find resolutions, the customer would have already bought the RDP CALS. We will come to know about the issue only when we start using the RDP environment, and if resolution is not possible or requires extra cost, the customer will be upset.

Comment: To get an idea, this might be a better read, in addition to the technet  http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/vdi-articles/microsoft-hyper-v/how-configure-microsoft-rds-universal-printing-deepdive.html  Things happen during usage scenarios. It depends on the scenarios and any system can raise issues. XP can be a huge problem unless you at least utilize a remediation setup. It is no longer continued by Microsoft. The requirements are about the RDC (remote desktop client). Please also see new changes to RDS: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831447(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: Requirements to use easy print is normally XP sp3. Vista SP2 prefered, to avoid issue..Net 3.5 at least, RDC version 6.1 and onward. If Vista SP2 clients are present, they can use RDC 7.0 without the .Net 3.5 requirement, however, all systems must be up to date.